# Hide navigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uinavigationbar

I have some problems that I do not understand.

I would like hide my navigation bar on scroll on my , I made 2 different solutions:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    lastOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}

- (void) scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    bool hide = (scrollView.contentOffset.y > lastOffsetY);
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:hide animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f", self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y, self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.frame.origin.y, self.webView.frame.origin.y, self.view.superview.frame.origin.y);
}
```

Or the second solution:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGRect frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
    CGFloat size = frame.size.height - 21;
    CGFloat framePercentageHidden = ((20 - frame.origin.y) / (frame.size.height - 1));
    CGFloat scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat scrollDiff = scrollOffset - lastOffsetY;
    CGFloat scrollHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height + scrollView.contentInset.bottom;

    if (scrollOffset <= -scrollView.contentInset.top) {
        frame.origin.y = 20;
    } else if ((scrollOffset + scrollHeight) >= scrollContentSizeHeight) {
        frame.origin.y = -size;
    } else {
        frame.origin.y = MIN(20, MAX(-size, frame.origin.y - scrollDiff));
    }

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:frame];

    [self updateBarButtonItems:(1 - framePercentageHidden)];
    lastOffsetY = scrollOffset;


    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self stoppedScrolling];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                  willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate) {
        [self stoppedScrolling];
    }
}

- (void)stoppedScrolling
{
    CGRect frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
    if (frame.origin.y < 20) {
        [self animateNavBarTo:-(frame.size.height - 21)];
    }

    NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f", self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y, self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.frame.origin.y, self.webView.frame.origin.y, self.view.superview.frame.origin.y);
}

- (void)updateBarButtonItems:(CGFloat)alpha
{
    [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIBarButtonItem* item, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop) {
        item.customView.alpha = alpha;
    }];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIBarButtonItem* item, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop) {
        item.customView.alpha = alpha;
    }];
    self.navigationItem.titleView.alpha = alpha;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor colorWithAlphaComponent:alpha];
}

- (void)animateNavBarTo:(CGFloat)y
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        CGRect frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
        CGFloat alpha = (frame.origin.y >= y ? 0 : 1);
        frame.origin.y = y;
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:frame];
        [self updateBarButtonItems:alpha];
    }];
}
```

With the first, the navigation bar animation is great, the webView take bounds of my screen and the status bar is under the webView, that's not very nice.

with the second, the navigation bar does animation correctly, I have my status bar with correct background, but my webView stay static, I've a white background under the navigationBar old position and the webView doesn't follow my navigation bar.

My question is, how can I make like `setNavigationBarHidden` apple function ?

Thank's

Comment: Are you developing for iOS 8.0 and above? If yes, you can set `hidesBarsOnSwipe` property of `UINavigationController` to YES

Comment: Yes, but I really want change position of the navbar with the scroll, like Instagram do for exemple.

Comment: have you tried setting `hidesBarOnSwipe` to YES? In my opinion, the result is pretty similar to what most apps is doing and it is quick fix. Unless you also want some kind effect like scaling and fading that Instagram is doing

Comment: Yes but the result is the same as `setNavigationBarHidden` ... the webView is under the statusBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I roughly get what kind animation you want.

For your second solution, you need to change `frame` property of UIWebView as well.

```
// get UIWebView frame here
CGRect webViewRect = _webView.frame;

if (scrollOffset <= -scrollView.contentInset.top) {
    frame.origin.y = 20;
} else if ((scrollOffset + scrollHeight) >= scrollContentSizeHeight) {
    frame.origin.y = -size;
} else {
    frame.origin.y = MIN(20, MAX(-size, frame.origin.y - scrollDiff));
}
webViewRect.origin.y = frame.origin.y + frame.size.height;

if ( webViewRect.origin.y != _webView.frame.origin.y ) {
    [_webView setFrame:webViewRect];
}
```

I do not have complete picture of your view architecture, but if by moving `_webView` up, `_webView` end up too short on bottom, you can increase the height of `_webView` equivalent to height of navigation bar and set its content inset with bottom edge the height of navigation bar. Something like this:

```
_webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height+self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];
[_webView.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, 0.0)];
```

Comment: Indeed, I was actually doing it and the result look great ! Thank's a lot :)

Comment: Your welcome. Actually, Apple did have the animation that you wanted on first beta of iOS 8 and even showcasing it on one of wwdc videos and then, they removed it...

Comment: Yes that's true ! I like this animation, it's a pleasure for eyes to  haven't navigationbar anytime, especially when you have some text, an article for example.